# IObjectSet Include Extension Method Errors with CompiledQuery

Tags: entity-framework-4

In my Custom ObjectContext class I have my entity collections exposed as IObjectSet so they can be unit-tested.  I have run into a problem when I use this ObjectContext in a compiled query and call the "Include" extension method (From Julie Lerman's blog http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/agile-entity-framework-4-repository-part-5-iobjectset/):

```cs
public IQueryable<MyPocoObject> RunQuery(MyCustomContext context, int theId)
{
    var query = CompiledQuery.Compile<MyCustomContext, int, IQueryable<MyPocoObject>>(
         (ctx, id) => ctx.MyPocoObjects.Include("IncludedPocoObject").Where(n => n.IncludedPocoObject.id == id));

    return query(context, theId);
}
```

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyPocoObject] Include[MyIncludedPocoObject](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyPocoObject], System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

If I use this same query on ObjectSet collections rather than IObjectSet it works fine.  If I simply run this query without precompiling it works fine.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I am running into the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I've just misunderstood as you seem to have been looking at this for a while - But shouldn't you be including the ObjectSet not the object that is queried BY that object set.

eg:

```cs
    var query = CompiledQuery.Compile<MyCustomContext, int, IQueryable<MyPocoObject>>(
         (ctx, id) => ctx.MyPocoObjects
        .Include("IncludedPocoObjectSET")
        .Where(n => n.IncludedPocoObject.id == id));
```

Can you also confirm that running the same query without compiling doesn't throw the "can't translate" exception?

Comment: Here is an example of a query that throws when using IobjectSet and does not when using ObjectSet 
private static readonly Expression<Func<Database, string, IEnumerable<SiteAnnouncement>>> expression = (database, slug) => database.SiteAnnouncements.Include("UserCreated").Where(sa => sa.Site.Slug == slug);
private static readonly Func<Database, string, IEnumerable<SiteAnnouncement>> compiledQuery = CompiledQuery.Compile(expression);

Comment: Complete Error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[PostHope.Core.DomainObjects.SiteAnnouncement] Include[SiteAnnouncement](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[PostHope.Core.DomainObjects.SiteAnnouncement], System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: Ok, I may be a little out of my depth so apologies if this is nonsensical: When you refer to the objectset via the interface, it's the definition of the methods on the interface that is presented, not of the methods on the object - Are there any special attributes or compiler hints on the objectset's methods/properties after compilation (check with reflector) that aren't present on the interface?

Comment: Will try that. Thanks for taking the time to respond!